# How to display the change in the postgres table in real time using nodejs and socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, websocket, socket.io

In the postgresql database i have an "alarm" table, a peculiar alarm panel. 
I need to display the appearance of new events in real time. Using the socket.io library,
I was able to display notifications of new events, but I needed that the whole database was unloaded at startup,
 and in my cases this does not happen, I ask you how to implement it better, thanks in advance.

app.js

```
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(9999);
              var pg = require ('pg');

              var con_string = 'postgres://username:password@localhost/dbname';

              var pg_client = new pg.Client(con_string);
pg_client.connect();
var query = pg_client.query('LISTEN alarmevent');

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('connected', { connected: true });

    socket.on('ready for data', function (data) {
        pg_client.on('notification', function(title) {
            socket.emit('update', { message: title });
            console.log(title);
        });
    });
});
```

index.html

```
WEB_SOCKET_SWF_LOCATION = 'inc/WebSocketMain.swf';
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9999');
socket.on('connected', function (data) {
    socket.emit('ready for data', {});
});
socket.on('update', function (data) {
        $('#future').append(data.message.payload + "<br/>");
});
```

Comment: not sure if I understand that right. do you have an insert trigger that does call notify on insert for the alarm table? Or do you need to know how to create such trigger? What do you mean with unload database, delete all alarms? Why is that needed? To do things better: understand, when nobody listen for notification, postgres don't care. but you can search in alarm table. you append html to the page. if the app is public be aware of xss attacks. I think you don't need WebSocketMain.swf anymore today. pro tip: always be careful with different vocabulary, alarm in table,notify in pg,event in js.